# Is it more resource-efficient to run two threads under low load or a single thread under moderate load?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, epoll

Consider a client application that is going to receive UDP packets from the same IP address, but on different ports. The bit rates of both data streams are much lower than the overall network connection throughput (say, both are around 2 Kb/s). The machine running the client is going to have a modern ARMv7 or x86-64 CPU.

Which of the following two approaches is better in terms of efficient use of the target machine’s resources?

1. Run single-threaded, blocking on both sockets with the `epoll` system call, and read from one or both sockets sequentially.
2. Run in two threads, each dedicated to one of the two sockets, and use simple blocking I/O (not invoking `epoll`).

Is there a possibility of losing packets by following the first approach when both sockets have data? Does the answer change with different number of CPU cores available on the target machine?

Comment: 2Kb/second is almost nothing in today's world. So performance-wise I doubt there is any perceptible advantage to either method. Likewise, at these levels, I cannot see that there is any potential performance issue with even one core (and so you're unlikely to perceive any benefit from more than one).

Comment: If both methods are equal performance-wise, than running a single thread should be by a tiny fraction better because the time would have spent on context switch isn't wasted. Am I wrong?

Comment: *If* both threads have to be scheduled on the same CPU, yes. If on different CPUs, probably not. But at these work loads, the difference is almost certainly inconsequential anyway.

Comment: 1st approach saves memory used for another thread, while the code for 2nd approach is more maintainable.